# Can I write code with an expiration date?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I just had this idea for something that I'd love to be able to use:

Let's say I have to fix a bug and I decide to write an ugly code line that fixes the immediate problem - but only because I promise myself that I will soon find the time to perform a proper refactoring.

I want to be able to somehow mark that code line as "Expired in" and add a date - so that if the code is compiled some time after that date there will be a compilation error/warning with a proper message.

Any suggestions? It must be possible to perform - maybe using some complicated #IF or some options in visual studio?

I'm using VS 2005 - mainly for C#.

Comment: I think this is a terrible idea. It's pretty much the same concept as borrowing money to buy a house you can't afford. If you haven't got the time to write the code properly now, what are the chances that you, or whatever poor sod is left to maintain your hacks later, will have the time at some arbitrary date in the future? I hate it on too many levels to explain.

Comment: grenade - whilst i wholeheartedly agree in principle (i've been there picking up the pieces), i do think this is quite a quirky idea.

Comment: @jim absolutely, I even took a failed stab at it myself with conditional attributes. I like your example btw. From the perspective of fun coding problems its an interesting question. From the perspective of tooling support in the IDE that encourages new developers to get into code debt early and often, it stinks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could write comment lines in the form

```
// Expires on 2011/07/01
```

and add a prebuild step which does a solution-wide replace of these lines by something like

```
#error Code expired on 2011/07/01
```

for all lines that contain a date before the current day. For this prebuild step you would need to write a short program (probably using regular expressions and some date comparision logic)

This step could also be performed by a VS macro, which allows for easier access to all files fo the solution but has the disadvantage that it must be installed and run on all VS installations where your project is compiled.

Answer (score 32):

Mark the code with the `System.ObsoleteAttribute` attribute, you'll get a compiler warning, which will nag you to fix the code

```
[Obsolete("You've an ugly hack here")]
public void MyUglyHack()
{
...
}
```

Alternatively . . .

Write your own attribute, passing it an expiration date on the constructor, in the constructor throw an exception if `DateTime.Now >= expirationDate`.

The compile will fail until you fix the code (or more likely increase the expiration date, or *far more likely* you just remove the Attribute.

Comment: I think `Obsolete` only issues a warning, if the method is actually called somewhere. There is no warning on it if its called e.g. via an interface (i.e. the interface method is not marked obsolete but some implementing method is) or - even worse - it is called via reflection. Also you can only mark a whole method as obsolete whereas I think the OP wanted to mark single lines or sections of code.

Answer (score 27):

oooohhh - this is 'orrible. try this for a giggle:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All)]
public class BugExpiryAttribute : System.Attribute
{
    // don't tell 'anyone' about this hack attribute!!
    public BugExpiryAttribute(string bugAuthor, string expiryDate)
    {
        DateTime convertedDate = DateTime.Parse(expiryDate);
        Debug.Assert(DateTime.Now <= convertedDate, 
            string.Format("{0} promised to remove this by {1}", 
                bugAuthor, convertedDate.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")));
    }
}
```

then, decorate your method/class etc:

```
[BugExpiryAttribute("Jack Skit", "2011-01-01")]
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
...
}
```

... nasty :-)

**[DISCLAIMER]** - created in the name of academic interest, not production code finese!!

**[edit]** - just to clarify, code compiled and in production will continue to run on/after the 'bugExpriryDate'. only once the code is run in the compiler (on/after the date), will the warning message be raised (debug.assert). just thought it worth making that distinction - cheers MartinStettner.

**[caveat]** - if used in classes/methods etc would need to be read via reflection. however (and this is interesting) will work straight off in the compiler if used on `sub Main()`. how strange!! (thanks for the nod Hans...)

Comment: Nice! If you set the attribute parameter to "2012-12-21", it should make it fine to use MyUglyHack() for as long as we're all here. ;)

Comment: If I understand right, this code will stop *working* after the given date. The OP asked for some way to make the compiler stop *compiling* the code after a given date. Academically spoken, that's a little difference :) ...

Comment: martin - no, the code will continue to function after the date in the production environment (debug.assert). i think he said this '[snip]...so that if the code is _compiled_ some time after that date there will be a _compilation error/warning with a proper message_'. give this wee example a try, that's exactly what it does (i.e. compiled code [the dll/exe] will still work without any issue). However, the compiler will raise a warning in development on/after the 'warning' date. as i say, it ain't pretty - but demonstrates a quasi solution :-). i'm scottish, what more can i say!!

Comment: This code does nothing at all.  Attributes are useless without code that reads them.  The compiler certainly won't.

Comment: Hans - I had tried it on `sub Main()` without issue, hence my confident stride. how come it works flawlessly on `sub Main()` but not on class methods (without reflection reads). a good one to ponder further and homework for all!!

Answer (score 17):

I think this is the reason Visual Studio has a Task List. Add the comment:

```
\\ TODO: Fix this spaghetti by 01APR11
```

and it will show up like this

[image: Task List Pane].

the keywords are configurable from the options

[image: Task List Options]

Answer (score 7):

Well it doesn't do exactly what you're asking for but you could use a Debug.Assert() method call which would alert you (in Debug only) that the code has expired. One benefit would be that  it wouldn't inadvertently affect your production code (compilation or execution) but would be sufficiently annoying in Debug for you to want to correct it.

```
// Alert the developer after 01/07/2011
Debug.Assert(Date.Now < new DateTime(2011, 7, 1))
```

Comment: now, if you could refactor that out to a similar implementation to the System.ObsoleteAttribute attibute, it might be interesting.

Answer (score 7):

One more option if you have unit tests for your code you can time bomb the tests that verifies your fix. This way you don't introduce strange checks in your production code.

Also I think the best option if you have to put in hack (you've probably already spent enough time looking at it to fix properly... but still want a hack there) than open bug/create task/work item (whatever you use to track future work) and decide if you want to fix it later.

Answer (score 4):

With .NET 6+ this is quite simple when a source generator is used:

Source generator

```cs
    [Generator]
    public class ObsoleteFromDateSourceGenerator : ISourceGenerator
    {
        public void Execute(GeneratorExecutionContext context)
        {
            var currentDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
            ImmutableArray<AttributeSyntax> attributes = context.Compilation
                .SyntaxTrees.SelectMany(s => s.GetRoot().DescendantNodes())
                .Where((d) => d.IsKind(SyntaxKind.Attribute))
                .OfType<AttributeSyntax>()
                .Where(d => d.Name.ToString() == SourceGeneratorConstants.ObsoleteFromDateAttributeName)
                .ToImmutableArray();

            foreach (var attribute in attributes)
            {
                try
                {
                    var semanticModel = context.Compilation.GetSemanticModel(attribute.SyntaxTree);

                    var argumentDate = attribute.ArgumentList?.Arguments.FirstOrDefault()?.Expression;
                    var argumentMessage = attribute.ArgumentList?.Arguments.Skip(1).FirstOrDefault()?.Expression;

                    if (argumentDate != null)
                    {
                        var date = DateTime.ParseExact(semanticModel.GetConstantValue(argumentDate).ToString(), SourceGeneratorConstants.ObsoleteFromDateAttributeDateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

                        string? message = null;
                        if (argumentMessage is not null
                            && semanticModel.GetConstantValue(argumentMessage) is Optional<object> tmp
                            && tmp.HasValue)
                        {
                            message = tmp.Value?.ToString();
                        }

                        var diagnostic = Diagnostic.Create(DiagnosticDescriptors.ObsoleteFromDate(message, /*isWarning:*/ currentDate < date), attribute.GetLocation());

                        context.ReportDiagnostic(diagnostic);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw new ArgumentNullException(paramName: "date");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    var diagnostic = Diagnostic.Create(DiagnosticDescriptors.ObsoleteFromDateError(ex.Message), attribute.GetLocation());
                    context.ReportDiagnostic(diagnostic);
                }
            }
        }

        public void Initialize(GeneratorInitializationContext context)
        {
        }
    }
```

Some constants

```cs
    public static class SourceGeneratorConstants
    {
        public const string ObsoleteFromDateAttributeName = "ObsoleteFromDate";
        public const string ObsoleteFromDateAttributeDateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd";
    }
```

Build diagnostics

```cs
    public static class DiagnosticDescriptors
    {
        public const string Category = "BNX";
        public const string ErrorTitle = "Source code error";
        
        public static readonly Func<string?, bool, DiagnosticDescriptor> ObsoleteFromDate = (message, isWarning) => new DiagnosticDescriptor(
            id: $"{Category}{SourceGeneratorConstants.ObsoleteFromDateAttributeName}",
            title: "Obsolete code",
            messageFormat: message ?? "Obsolete code, please review",
            category: Category,
            defaultSeverity: isWarning ? DiagnosticSeverity.Warning : DiagnosticSeverity.Error,
            isEnabledByDefault: true);

        public static readonly Func<string?, DiagnosticDescriptor> ObsoleteFromDateError = (message) => new DiagnosticDescriptor(
            id: $"{Category}{SourceGeneratorConstants.ObsoleteFromDateAttributeName}",
            title: ErrorTitle,
            messageFormat: $"Unable to parse {SourceGeneratorConstants.ObsoleteFromDateAttributeName} attribute because of error: {message} Expecting the following syntax: [{SourceGeneratorConstants.ObsoleteFromDateAttributeName}(\"{SourceGeneratorConstants.ObsoleteFromDateAttributeDateFormat}\", \"message\")]",
            category: Category,
            defaultSeverity: DiagnosticSeverity.Error,
            isEnabledByDefault: true);
    }
```

A custom attribute

```cs
    /// <summary>
    /// Triggers a build error at and after a specific system date. Source generators must be included in the project.
    /// </summary>
    public class ObsoleteFromDateAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public const string DateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd";

        /// <summary>
        /// Build error message.
        /// </summary>
        public string Message { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// System date at and after which the build error should occur.
        /// </summary>
        public string Date { get; }


        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="ObsoleteFromDateAttribute"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="date">Required. System date at and after which the build error should occur. Expected format: <see cref="DateFormat"/></param>
        /// <param name="message">Optional. Build error message.</param>
        public ObsoleteFromDateAttribute(string date, string message): base()
        {
            Date = date;
            Message = message;
        }
    }
```

And finally a test:

```cs
    // The following should result in a build error
    [ObsoleteFromDate("2000-01-01", "We are waiting for some Jira thing 1 to complete")]
    public class ObsoleteClass1
    {
    }

    // The following should result in a build warning
    [ObsoleteFromDate("3000-01-01", "We are waiting for some Jira thing 2 to complete")]
    public class ObsoleteClass2
    {
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Without controlling the compiler (possible in the 5.0 timeframe with compiler as a service?), you are not going to have your code expire. You can mark the code as deprecated, or use the Obsolete attribute, or similar, to fire off a warning, but people can ignore warnings (many devs I have met have not learned the rule that warnings are errors).

I think it is a lot of work to try to protect people from themselves. It is even harder when you are protecting them from themselves in the future. Mark the code as a kludge and leave it at that.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of embedding a time bomb, perhaps consider applying a [BUGBUG: comment](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/larryosterman/archive/2005/03/29/403439.aspx)?

Rather than forcing you or someone else to fix code that may be kind of unsightly but works as expected down the road, you can just do a solution-wide search and find the ugly bits when you decide it's time to get down and refactor the really ugly stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Track it in a bug instead.  Then it can be properly scheduled and prioritized with other refactoring work.

`TODO` comments in code can have a tendency to be lost and forgotten.  Throwing a compiler error after a particular date will likely lead to that date being pushed forward, or the comment/attribute removed.

Answer (score 0):

I hope i can help with this. take 2 datetimepicker on tool box. And just convert 1 datetimepicker.

```
private void expired()
{
DateTime expired = DateTime.Parse(Convert.ToDateTime(datetimepicker1.Text).ToString());
DateTime compare = DateTime.Parse(Convert.ToDateTime(datetimepicker2.Text).ToString());

if(expired < compare)
{
MessageBox.Show("This product is expired!");
}
else
}
MessageBox.Show("This product is not expired");
{
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Both **TIME** and **DATE** emit strings and, to my knowledge, there is no way to parse them out at the preprocessing stage.

There are a few methods you can easily do in code to ensure that the code at least warns you at run time. Including an assert is one way, putting in a code comment also works, but the way I handle it is through including a doxygen comment with a note explaining that the function contains a hack, bug, or performance issue that needs to be resolved. This ends up getting filtered by many programmers and is easily viewable on the website for myself or other people to fix.