# Obsolete after a specific date?

Tags: c#, deprecated, custom-attributes, obsolete

I would like to mark a method/class... obsolete but only after a specific date. For example this class will be obsolete in 6 month to let other developers to get time to implements the new architecture.

Is there an existing attribute in C# doing that ? Or should I implement my own ?

All projects treat warnings as errors, so the ObsoleteAttribute do not answer this question.

Comment: If you're treating all warnings as errors, shouldn't you be fixing the warnings by not using deprecated code?

Comment: There is no in built functionality to do this.

Comment: You have to use Obsolete. This force developers to change their code as soon as possible. Give them ability use fresh code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write a code with expiration date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5222015/how-to-write-a-code-with-expiration-date)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of baking this information into the code, you would usually publish the roadmap of development with any breaking changes that are going to occur. Deprecated features are not necessarily breaking changes.

Even if you code a mechanism for the IDE to consume this "deferred deprecation", the other developers would also need this VS extension in order to consume it.

Just release a document saying what is going to be deprecated/broken and then deprecate it using the attribute when the time comes.

The "treat warnings as errors" would only impact you at the point of deprecation, but this implies that you are vigilant in migrating off of old code and onto newer code. Of course, if you need to provide backwards compatibility you would either need to stop treating warnings as errors (in order to have code that uses deprecated code for support) or suppress the warnings at the point of deprecation, but this can get a little messy.

There is no built in support for deferred deprecation and I don't know of any third party solutions in the wild - so for now you are on your own.

Comment: I agree. The problem is other developers use the same source code but we have dedicated part. So changing the way of my classes impact orthers

Answer (score 2):

What if you start your methods with something like this ?

```
void method()
{
    if(System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) // you want your application to work, but warn developers
    {
        string DeprecatedFrom = "20001231"; //example date: 31 dec 2000
        if (string.Format("{0:yyyymmdd}",DateTime.Now).Equals(DeprecatedFrom)) throw new NotSupportedException("Don't use this method.");
    }
}
```

Crude, but effective: method will start throwing when 31 dec 2000 (in the example) is reached.

Comment: Take that idea a little further and use Code Contracts to enforce the date :-) That said, if this is consumed by third parties I would shy away from throwing exceptions just because I don't want them using old code - every change you make would be a breaking change.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth I'm not very familiar with code contracts, please post some code in your own answer! Concept sounds interesting.

Comment: I'm not going to post it in my own answer because I disagree with it almost entirely as the proposed solution. Read up on Code Contracts (now in .NET 4), the code required to do this would be fairly simple and not too dissimilar to your current code: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264808.aspx

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth Definitely checking that out. Thanks.

Comment: This can go even further, use an Aspect Oriented Programming framework like [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/) in order to decorate the method with an attribute like `ToBeDeprecated("20121231")`.